# How to Replace Bootstrap Carousel Indicators with Thumbnails

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Can you Please let me know How I can replace Bootstrap Carousel Indicators with Thumbnails? What I would Like to have is having a list of thums at the bottom of the image slider?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the source of [Bootstrap's site](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/javascript.html#carousel), it seems like this is the markup in the carousel:

```
      <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">
            <ol class="carousel-indicators">
              <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
              <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
              <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
            </ol>
            <div class="carousel-inner">
              <div class="item active">
                <img src="assets/img/bootstrap-mdo-sfmoma-01.jpg" alt="">
                <div class="carousel-caption">
                  <h4>**This is where**</h4>
                  <p>**the caption is defined**</p>
                </div>
              </div>
              .....
```

You can try experimenting with replacing the contents of the carousel-caption div with your thumbnails.